# Why does this ffmpeg command work in bash and not zsh?

Tags: bash, zsh, quoting, url

Today I got home from work (run bash on an Ubuntu box) and tried to run some code on my local arch box with my beloved zsh and the commands were failing?

The command is below with the personal info and ip changed obviously

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://user:pass@my.webserver.org:5554/my-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264  -threads 3 -vcodec copy -f segment -segment_time 2 outfiles/cam_out%04d.mp4
```

It runs perfect in bash, but when I run it in zsh I get the error

```
zsh: no matches found: rtsp://user:pass@my.webserver.org:5554/my-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264
```

Why has my beloved zsh betrayed me?

Comment: Try to put rtsp link into single quotes.

Comment: you're my hero :) I knew zsh wouldn't let me down.

Comment: Try after `mkdir -p 'rtsp://user:pass@my.webserver.org:5554/my-media/media.amp-videocodec=h264'` and then both bash and zsh will fail you. At least zsh shows you your mistake here.

Comment: @cuonglm, I meant that when there's a file matching the pattern, both zsh and bash will "fail" in that the glob will be expanded. zsh's behaviour is saner in that when there's no match, it makes you realise your mistake.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In string:

```
rtsp://user:pass@my.webserver.org:5554/my-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264
```

you have `?` in that string, so the shell will perform [pathname expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_06) on that string, using [pattern matching](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13) rules.

In `bash`, if `failglob` options was not set, which is default, then failed pattern will be left as-is:

```
$ echo does-not-exist?
does-not-exist?
```

---

While `zsh` will report no pattern match error with `nomatch` option set, which is default:

```
$ echo does-not-exist?
zsh: no matches found: does-not-exist?
```

You can make `zsh` suppress the error and print the pattern:

```
$ setopt nonomatch
$ echo does-not-exist?
does-not-exist?
```

---

You can make `bash` behave like `zsh` with `nomatch` option set, by turning on `failglob`:

```
$ shopt -s failglob
$ echo does-not-exist?
bash: no match: does-not-exist?
```

---

More general, you can disable shell filename generation:

```
$ set -f
$ : "The command"
$ set +f
```

(or `set -o noglob`, `set +o noglob`)

or using one of shell [quoting](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02) methods to make the shell treats `?` and other pattern matching special characters literally.

---

`zsh` also provide the `noglob` builtin, which disable filename generation in any words for the following simple command:

```
$ noglob echo *
*
```

Comment: oh wow that's kind of embarrassing to have missed, thanks for the nice reply.

Comment: But now this makes me question: How would someone fix it? By using quotes? Something else? Overly-complicated cat+subshells? It would be nice if you added this to your answer, to make it a bit more general and still very complete and correct.

Comment: Now THAT is an awesome answer! I've upvoted accordingly. The answer was really lacking the last bit. It told what's wrong but not the fix. Thank you.

Comment: Another alternative:  In zsh, you can disable globbing only for the current command by prepending `noglob` to the command.  E.g. `noglob echo *` will simply output `*`.